# Wilcoxon test for two groups or post hoc analysis of K-W test when I woud like to compare two groups and observe the difference?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

I am working on data analysis. I divided my samples into five different groups (group A-E) by using some variables. and then, because group A can be further reclassified into group A+ and group A- and I did that, so there were 7 groups in total.
My research goal is to compare the difference of group A+ and group A-, so should I just use wilcoxon test to compare group A+ and group A- or K-W method to compare group A+, group A-, group C-E with post hoc analysis of DunnTest?
Because when I used wilcoxon test, there were some variables between group A- and group A+ showing difference but when I used K-W method with post hoc analysis, tehre were no differences between two groups.
Could you please clarify and assist me to figure out?
Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.